# Akka Management: Adding liveness check to my application

Tags: akka

I am working with Akka and have to add some custom implementation to Liveness check for a usecase.

Following the Akka documentation at [Configuring health checks](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-management/current/healthchecks.html#configuring-health-checks), I added the following configuration to my application:

```
akka {
  management {
    health-checks {
      liveness-checks {
        cluster-liveness = "ie.fd.cpoi.acl.liveness.LivenessCheck"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have created the class, implementing `Supplier<CompletionStage<Boolean>>` as:

```
package ie.fd.cpoi.acl.liveness

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import org.slf4j.{Logger, LoggerFactory}

import scala.concurrent.Future

class LivenessCheck(system: ActorSystem) extends (() => Future[Boolean]) {

  val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("LivenessCheck")

  override def apply(): Future[Boolean] = {
    logger.info("Making call to a dependent system here. We need to restart the app if its down")
    Future.successful(false)
  }
}
```

But somehow Akka is not picking up the liveness check:

```
[INFO ] 2021-10-04 16:20:45.164+0000 [cpoi-ha-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] a.m.i.HealthChecksImpl - Loading liveness checks []
```

Can somene help me with what I am missing here?

Comment: `Supplier<CompletionStage<Boolean>>` is Java, while `() => Future[Boolean]` is Scala.  Anyway, you may want to check that you've added the configuration to something included from `application.conf`.

Comment: Yes, it's in a configuration file included in ```application.conf```. Rest of the configurations working fine. I was wondering if adding Akka Cluster impacts the liveness checks.